# bp_activity_add() not working in theme ajax hooks

Tags: ajax, android-activity, buddypress

I am trying to add an activity for the current user through a function hooked to wp_ajax

```
add_action("wp_ajax_add_pair", "some_function");

function some_function(){
$args = array("action"=>"action string");
bp_activity_add($args);
}
```

some_function is called through ajax but I get bp_activity_add does not exist. This makes me think that BP hasnt loaded yet, but var_dump($bp) shows the variable is set. So need help to record activity for a user through ajax

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to enable activity streams from the backend! worked for me!